# Creole syntax for external links for a wiki

Tags: wiki, creole

Would like to know if there's any Creole syntax for having external links displayed on a new window.

Basic syntax on links: 
**HTML**
`<a href="http://www.wikicreole.org/">http://www.wikicreole.org/</a>`

**CREOLE**
`[[http://www.wikicreole.org/]]`

**What about this?**
**HTML**
`<a href="link" target="_blank">link</a>`
**CREOLE**  
???

Note: There's **target=_blank**.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

[WikiCreole](http://wikicreole.org/wiki/Home) cheatsheet indicate `[[URL|description]]` but I got it working on GitHub wiki (using Creole language) with: `[[This is an example|http://example.com]]`

Comment: How do you add `target="_blank"` (html version) to the creole syntax?

Comment: wiki syntax doesn't support HTML <a> target Attribute. I guess this should be set up in the wiki settings.